# How to insert new line just after method and type annotations using Eclipse JDT code formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm using Eclipse JDT API to format my generated java source files.
With which options I can force formatter to make the output as like below:

```
@Annotation1 
@Annotation2
@Annotation3
@Annotation4 
public class TheClass {

    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    @Annotation5 
    private Object o1;

    @Annotation5 
    private Object o2;


    @Annotation6
    @Annotation7 
    public void doSomething(@Annotation8 @Annotation Object dto) {
         // some works
    }
}
```

As I know the `DefaultCodeFormatterOptions` has `insert_new_line_after_annotation` field that adds new line after all annotations, Even the method parameter annotations. But I want to add new-line just after type method or type annotations

`Edit:`

this is the formatter code :

```
public String format(String code)
        throws MalformedTreeException, BadLocationException {
    Map options = new java.util.HashMap();
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_SOURCE, "1.5");
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_COMPLIANCE, "1.5");
    options.put(JavaCore.COMPILER_CODEGEN_TARGET_PLATFORM, "1.5");

    DefaultCodeFormatterOptions cfOptions =
            DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.getDefaultSettings();
    cfOptions.insert_new_line_after_annotation = false;
    cfOptions.comment_insert_new_line_for_parameter = true;

    cfOptions.blank_lines_before_method = 1;
    cfOptions.number_of_empty_lines_to_preserve= 1;

    cfOptions.tab_char = DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.SPACE;

    CodeFormatter cf = new DefaultCodeFormatter(cfOptions, options);

    TextEdit te = cf.format(CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN, code, 0,
            code.length(), 0, null);
    IDocument dc = new Document(code);

    te.apply(dc);
    return dc.get();
}
```

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DefaultCodeFormatterOptions](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blame/master/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/DefaultCodeFormatterOptions.java) has separate fields for new line after annotations for every possible context of the annotation

```
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_type;
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_field;
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_method;
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_package;
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_parameter;
public boolean insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_local_variable;
```

So I'm guessing `insert_new_line_after_annotation_on_type` is the answer... I've checked this behaves as expected with the IDE itself rather than the API.

This is a relatively new addition added by [this commit](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/commit/90a561fc4554bf1cfedd4387faeef02d32d66ca5) in February 2014 to fix [bug/feature 425040](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425040). It's available in the eclipse in front of me 4.4.0

Comment: I'm using the API. Not the Eclipse IDE

Comment: Yes. I have changed the dependency from    `org.eclipse.jdt>core>3.3.0-v_771` to `org.eclipse.jdt>org.eclipse.jdt.core>3.7.1`. Now I can see mentioned field attributes